# The application cannot access the iOS keychain in Xamarin.Forms but works in Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

Hello I am learning using MSAL but met a wired issue. I totally followed the [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c), and I am using the sample code. But I still got this exception building the client in **App.xaml.cs**:

> microsoft.identity.client.msalclientexception: the application cannot
> access the ios keychain for the application publisher (the team id is
> null). this is needed to enable single sign on between applications of
> the same publisher. this is an ios configuration issue. see
> https://aka.ms/msal-net-enable-keychain-access for more details on
> enabling keychain access.

```
AuthenticationClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(Constants.ClientId)
                .WithIosKeychainSecurityGroup(Constants.IosKeychainSecurityGroups)
                .WithB2CAuthority(Constants.AuthoritySignin)
                .WithRedirectUri($"msal{Constants.ClientId}://auth")
                .Build();
```

Relative Settings are as follows:

**info.plist:**

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>ADB2C Auth</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>msal....</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>None</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>URL Type 1</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

**ioskeychain in Contants.cs**:

```
 // set to a unique value for your app, such as your bundle identifier. Used on iOS to share keychain access.
        static readonly string iosKeychainSecurityGroup = "com.xamarin.adb2cauthorization";
```

**Entitlements.plist:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.xamarin.adb2cauthorization</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

**AppDelegate:**

```
public override bool OpenUrl(UIApplication app, NSUrl url, NSDictionary options)
        {
            AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(url);
            return base.OpenUrl(app, url, options);
        }
```

And I tried to upgrade the Microsoft.Identity.Client to v4.17.1, it is still not working. Since the share code is working for the Android part, I am really not sure what I could be missing. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: My bad. I updated it.

Comment: there is a section that specifically mentions "the teamid is null" - https://damienaicheh.github.io/azure/xamarin/xamarin.forms/2019/07/01/sign-in-with-microsoft-account-with-xamarin-en.html

Comment: Thanks I read this article. I think it is the same as [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/authentication/azure-ad-b2c)?

Comment: that doc does not mention team ID at all, where the link I gave you has an entire section devoted to the **specific error message** that you are getting

Comment: Yes. But the way the article mentioned to work with info.plist and Entitlements.plist is the same as the doc? And the doc is even more updated?

Comment: My bad. I missed this step: "Then open the project settings and in the iOS Bundle Signing select the Entitlements.plist inside the Custom Entitlements property." Maybe you can add an answer so I can accept it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 5):

Go to the ios project properties => iOS Bundle Signing and select your Entitlements.plist.

The Entitlements.plist file should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>$(AppIdentifierPrefix)com.microsoft.adalcache</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Also; it is imporant to set this file as custom entitlments in maui oder xamarin (ios settings)

Comment: do i need to swap this appItendifierPrefix with anything? like the bundle Id?

Comment: @inno No just use the file above

Comment: Also; it is imporant to set this file as custom entitlments in maui oder xamarin (ios settings)