# Visual Studio MacOS - iOS App Signing, Provisioning, and TeamID - MSAL Authentication

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, azure-ad-msal, visual-studio-mac, apple-developer

I have developed a full app in Xamarin on my windows machine, and have the android version working quite well. I am now trying to build this for iOS (for which is specifically purchased a 2020 Mac mini) and I am having one hell of a time.

***[Preamble] - skippable.***
First, I had to purchase a Mac, then I had to pay to join the developer program and get a team ID, then I had to reinstall visual studio 3 times as it kept giving me "unknown token g" in any project I tried to create or open. Then I couldn't get my app to run due to a missing team id for small authentication, so I tried to set up provisioning, but don't own a device and went down a rabbit hole there, and then cleared all that work to get back to the start.

**[Question]**
Where I am at right now, is that when I try to open my application, it gets to the starting page (the sign in page) and then throws up an error. Unfortunately its not copy/pastable as its on the divide simulator screen as a popup, but the basic GIST.

```
Xamarin.ios.4.22.0.0.MsalClientException
cannot_access_publisher_keychain Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalClientException
The application cannot access the iOS keychain for the application publisher (TeamId is null). This is needed to enable SingleSignOn between applications of the same publisher
```

It then goes on to give me a long stack trace of the identity client token cache accessor, platformoproxy etc.

**Things of note:**
I am using azure to host the web service.
Also using azure B2C to secure the service (hence sign in needed).
This is working on the android project, so my keys are correct.
Yes I am signed in with my Apple ID to visual studio.
Yes I have a teamID that I cans ee online and in my keychain certs.
I may have created multiple certs in trying to get this solved.... don't know if that could be an issue?
I can't set up a profile and use automatic provision as I do not have an iOS device - I just want to run this via the simulator.
My certs are apple development.
My info.plist has my bundle identifier (com.myappname.myapp).
My entitlements has keychain access groups with $(AppIdentifierPrefix).com.microsoft.adalcache

How and where do I add my team id so that I can run the simulator, and sign into my app using iOS? Is this a poorly formatted error and this has nothing to do with my team id or appidentifierprefix and something else is wrong? or have I missed something? I have search all day, and tried signing into Xcode and linking my profile there, different ways of setting up certificates, different plist values, provisioning (which fails - either won't let me auto provision as I don't have a profile because I have no divice, or if I set it to manual it just says it cannot find a profile)

I am at a loss.

I am an android guy and always avoid Mac - but I have to get the iOS version built and I am totally lost on what apple wants from me here

**edit**

Worth noting I have since added the following - still no luck.

- Added an iOS redirect URI to my b2c client (msauth.com.myapp.app://auth).
- Added the following to my plist.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>msauthv2</string>
    <string>msauthv3</string>
</array>

// And under my CFBundleURLSchemes
<string>msauth.com.myapp.app</string>
```

**Also worth noting**

> Then open the project settings and in the iOS Bundle Signing select
> the Entitlements.plist inside the Custom Entitlements property.

Did this too... However the second I add this, I get:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(3,3): Error: Could not find any available provisioning profiles for MyApp.iOS on iOS.
         (MyApp.iOS)
```

Hence my whole mention of issues with profiles.
not sure if my entitlements has a problem?

**Even more info**

Ive been triple checking https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-xamarin-native/tree/master/UserDetailsClient/UserDetailsClient.iOS

My previous setup had a different name for the CFBundleUrlName was just something random from a tutorial "ADB2C Auth" and is working on android, but this link above had it set to the bundle name, so I tried that (both adding a new one to the array, and replacing the existing) And same issue - without entitlements linked, I get the auth msal error - with entitlements linked I can't even build and get the profiles error.

**I also keep getting the spotlight crash error many have reported under the latest OS/Xcode**

I really do not know what I have done wrong here... I feel like I have tried everything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63272380/the-application-cannot-access-the-ios-keychain-in-xamarin-forms-but-works-in-and

Comment: Yes I saw that post, but there is no answer... just a comment that says a link specifically mentions this issue and when I click that link I end up on an error page. Also I have seen another page menetioning this issue, and all it said was to make sure entitlements was selected in the signing... which mine is. And I stillahve this problem

Comment: Also, see updates in Question - when I add this, I get a new error

Comment: `Could not find any available provisioning profiles for`, choose automatic provisioning and test in simulator.  To create a correct provisioning profile, please read this [docuemtn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/capabilities/?tabs=macos#creating-an-app-id-with-an-app-service).

Comment: as I stated in the question, I can't. I don't own an iOS device. therefor I cannot make a profile, and therefore cannot use auto provision

Comment: You don't need a device and you can run it in simulator with automatic provisioning.